# Is retrotranslator-runtime dependency required?

Tags: maven, dependencies, proguard, retrotranslator

I forked a project and retrotranslated it.

https://github.com/jinahya/json-cdc

When I use that library, in an application, and tried to proguard it I got a bunch of warnings saying...

```
[proguard] Warning: ...: can't find referenced class ...retrotranslator.runtime13...
```

When I looked the library class, which is retrotranslated, I see that class refers retrotranslator's class.

Should `retrotranslator-runtimeXX` be added as a dependency or that library?

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:...
[INFO] com.my.lib
[INFO] \- net.sf...:retrotranslator-runtime13:jar:1.2.9:runtime
[INFO]    \- backport...:backport-util-concucrrent-java12:jar:3.1:runtime
```

Or, should the application using the library add them by themselves?

Or, Doesn't it needed to be added at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option for embedding retrotranslator-related classes.

```
-embed <package>
```

e.g.

```
-embed com.your.retrotranslator
```

And then those required classes from [Retrotranslator](http://retrotranslator.sourceforge.net/) are embedded in your final classes.